# Absolute value of complex numbers in Calc?

Tags: calc

If I do this in Calc mode:

```
' 7i-2
```

It will enter the symbolic algebraic term `7i - 2`, which is displayed like so:

```
--- Emacs Calculator Mode ---
1:  7 i - 2
    .
```

However, if I run `A` (`calc-abs`), I only see this:

```
--- Emacs Calculator Mode ---
1:  abs(7 i - 2)
    .
```

In reality, the absolute value of `7i - 2` [is `sqrt(53)`.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C7i%20-%202%7C) How can I get such a result to show up in Calc mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to evaluate the algebraic `7i - 2` by pressing <kbd>=</kbd>, such that it is rewritten as `(-2, 7)`. Then you can use `calc-abs` just like you would on a normal number.

See also the [section on complex formats in the Calc manual.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Complex-Formats.html)

Comment: Thanks! `=` is exactly what I was looking for. Also, thanks for pointing me to that part of the manual... I had already seen it, but missed the part about `=`.